# What is the right regular expression to parse an error log in C#?

Tags: .net, regex

I have an error log from a crashing application that I use with a regular expression to pull details from. It looks like this:

```
const string errorLog = "Some preamble\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Exception Description: User did something that broke everything in sight.\r\n" +
    "Entity 'Arbitrary data 0001'\r\n" +
    "Asset: 'Invalid'\r\n" +
    "Host 'More random waffle'\r\n" +
    "uvScale: 1.00 1.00\r\n" +
    "uvOffset: 0.00  0.00\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "Crash Digest: 1234567890abcef1234567890abcdef\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n";
```

What I want to see is this:

```
User did something that broke everything in sight.
Entity 'Arbitrary data 0001'
Asset: 'Invalid'
Host 'More random waffle
uvScale: 1.00 1.00
uvOffset: 0.00  0.00
```

So the code I've been using is this:

```
const string regex = @"^Exception Description:\s*(Assert:\s*)?\s*(Assert failed!\s*)?(?<Description>.*?)$";
var matchDescription = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(errorLog);
var errorLogDescription = ((matchDescription.Success) ? matchDescription.Groups["Description"].Value.Trim() : "");
Console.WriteLine(errorLogDescription);
```

This generates this:

```
User did something that broke everything in sight.
```

which is missing the extra lines before Crash Digest: appears.

So I tried the following:

```
const string regex = @"Exception Description:\s*(Assert:\s*)?\s*(Assert failed!\s*)?(?<Description>.*?)(Crash Digest:)?$";
var matchDescription = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(errorLog);
```

which pulls everything after Exception Description which is too much.

I tried this alternative:

```
const string regex = @"Exception Description:\s*(Assert:\s*)?\s*(Assert failed!\s*)?(?<Description>.*)$";
var matchDescription = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(errorLog);
```

with the same results.

Can anyone figure out the regular expression that would work? Bear in mind Crash Digest may be missing too, in which case I'd expect just the first line.

Comment: Did the answer workout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture what comes after `Exception Description:`  in a group followed by all lines that do not start with `Crash Digest:`  using a negative lookahead.

```
Exception Description:[^\S\r\n]*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:).*)*)
```

- `Exception Description:[^\S\r\n]*` Match literally and optional whitespace chars without a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:).*)*` Optionally match all lines that do not start with `!Crash Digest:`
- `)` Close group 1

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/9Bruap) | [.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Exception+Description%3a%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%28.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!Crash+Digest%3a%29.*%29*%29&i=Some+preamble%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aException+Description%3a+User+did+something+that+broke+everything+in+sight.%0d%0aEntity+%27Arbitrary+data+0001%27%0d%0aAsset%3a+%27Invalid%27%0d%0aHost+%27More+random+waffle%27%0d%0auvScale%3a+1.00+1.00%0d%0auvOffset%3a+0.00++0.00%0d%0a%0d%0aCrash+Digest%3a+1234567890abcef1234567890abcdef%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble) *(Click on the Table tab to see the group 1 value)*

For example

```
string pattern = @"Exception Description:\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:).*)*)";
            const string errorLog = "Some preamble\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Some preamble...\r\n" +
    "Exception Description: User did something that broke everything in sight.\r\n" +
    "Entity 'Arbitrary data 0001'\r\n" +
    "Asset: 'Invalid'\r\n" +
    "Host 'More random waffle'\r\n" +
    "uvScale: 1.00 1.00\r\n" +
    "uvOffset: 0.00  0.00\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "Crash Digest: 1234567890abcef1234567890abcdef\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n" +
    "some postamble\r\n";
            Match m = Regex.Match(errorLog, pattern);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Output

```
User did something that broke everything in sight.
Entity 'Arbitrary data 0001'
Asset: 'Invalid'
Host 'More random waffle'
uvScale: 1.00 1.00
uvOffset: 0.00  0.00
```

---

If you only want to match the first line in group 1 if there is no `Crash Digest:` you can use a lookahead and also prevent crossing `Exception Description:`

If the exception should start at the beginning of the string, you can use an anchor `^`

```
^Exception Description:[^\S\r\n]*(.*(?:(?>\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:|Exception Description:).*)*(?=\r?\nCrash Digest:))?)
```

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eException+Description%3a%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%28.*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3e%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!Crash+Digest%3a%7cException+Description%3a%29.*%29*%28%3f%3d%5cr%3f%5cnCrash+Digest%3a%29%29%3f%29&i=Some+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aException+Description%3a+User+did+something+that+broke+everything+in+sight.%0d%0aEntity+%27Arbitrary+data+0001%27%0d%0aAsset%3a+%27Invalid%27%0d%0aHost+%27More+random+waffle%27%0d%0auvScale%3a+1.00+1.00%0d%0auvOffset%3a+0.00++0.00%0d%0a%0d%0aCrash+Digest%3a+1234567890abcef1234567890abcdef%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0a%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aSome+preamble...%0d%0aException+Description%3a+User+did+something+that+broke+everything+in+sight.%0d%0aEntity+%27Arbitrary+data+0001%27%0d%0aAsset%3a+%27Invalid%27%0d%0aHost+%27More+random+waffle%27%0d%0auvScale%3a+1.00+1.00%0d%0auvOffset%3a+0.00++0.00%0d%0a%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, it pulls in the Crash Digest and the post amble text. Also, the Exception doesn't start at the beginning of the string, it's after some preamble.

Comment: @imekon The first pattern does not have an anchor `^` See this regex101 link that the desired result is in capture group 1 https://regex101.com/r/C1BSag/1 which is highlighted in green and is shown in the example code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result I get when I run it as Regex code in C# doesn't match the web page you're showing.

Comment: @imekon Did you try the approach in the example code getting the value of capture group 1? Without a capture group, you could also use lookarounds to get a match only. If you also don't want to match empty lines: `(?<=Exception Description:[^\S\r\n]*)(\S.*(?:\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:|$).*)*)`

Comment: @imekon See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dException+Description%3a%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%29%28%5cS.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!Crash+Digest%3a%7c%5cr%3f%24%29.*%29*%29&i=Some+preamble...%0d%0aException+Description%3a+User+did+something+that+broke+everything+in+sight.%0d%0aEntity+%27Arbitrary+data+0001%27%0d%0aAsset%3a+%27Invalid%27%0d%0aHost+%27More+random+waffle%27%0d%0auvScale%3a+1.00+1.00%0d%0auvOffset%3a+0.00++0.00%0d%0a%0d%0atest%0d%0a%0d%0aCrash+Digest%3a+1234567890abcef1234567890abcdef%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0asome+postamble%0d%0a&o=m)

Comment: Ah, just worked out it's the Singleline/Multiline parameter setting. I left it as Singleline which breaks the matching; I noted in your 2nd example, you had it set to multiline, now it works. I'll try against other samples and see how it holds up.

Comment: Tried with other samples, and your regex fails when Assert: and Assert failed! are present; also when Crash Digest: is missing, your regex pulls in the rest of the error log instead of just the first line.

Comment: @imekon Can you add the text with some examples that should match to this link https://regex101.com/r/C1BSag/1 and then save it and share it again here in the comments? Can the part of the text that you want also contain empty lines?

Comment: This is my update to include the Assert text: (?<=Exception Description:[^\S\r\n]*)(Assert:\s*)?(Assert failed!\s*)?(\S.*(?:\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:|\r?$).*)*)

Comment: Your solution (with updates) works better than mine

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was to use the Regex to match the initial Exception Description, then move forwards to see if Crash Digest was present. It's not a Regex solution, but it does the job:

```
private static string FindErrlogDescription(string errlog)
{
    const string regexMatch = @"^Exception Description:\s*(Assert:\s*)?\s*(Assert failed!\s*)?(?<Description>.*)$";

    var regex = new Regex(regexMatch, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var matchDescription = regex.Match(errlog);

    if (!matchDescription.Success)
        return string.Empty;

    var remaining = errlog.Substring(matchDescription.Index + matchDescription.Length);
    var crashDigestPos = remaining.IndexOf("Crash Digest: ");

    if (crashDigestPos == -1)
        return matchDescription.Groups["Description"].Value.Trim();

    var full = matchDescription.Groups["Description"].Value + remaining.Substring(0, crashDigestPos);

    return full.Trim();
}
```

UPDATE: found The fourth bird's regex string catches more descriptions than my solution if I use this updated expression:

```
@"(?<=Exception Description:[^\S\r\n]*)(Assert:\s*)?(Assert failed!\s*)?(\S.*(?:\r?\n(?!Crash Digest:|\r?$).*)*)"
```